# Adding a search box form to my navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm new to front end design and am having challenges implementing a search box with filters into my navbar. I know this is potentially trivial but I have found it very challenging, and typically end up with a jumbled mess when I insert the searchbox code into my desired area (commented in the second code block).

The code for the search box is:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-xs-offset-2">
      <div class="input-group">
        <div class="input-group-btn search-panel">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
            <span id="search_concept">Filter by</span> <span class="caret"></span>
          </button>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a href="#contains">Contains</a></li>
            <li><a href="#its_equal">It's equal</a></li>
            <li><a href="#greather_than">Greather than ></a></li>
            <li><a href="#less_than">Less than < </a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#all">Anything</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <input type="hidden" name="search_param" value="all" id="search_param">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="x" placeholder="Search term...">
        <span class="input-group-btn">
          <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
          </button>
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The code for my nav bar is as follows, with a comment indicating where I need the search box to go:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
    </div>
    <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>

        <li>
          <!--SEARCH BAR HERE -->
        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="./">Log in</a></li>
        <li><a href="./">Join us</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter color-twitter"></i></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook color-facebook"></i></a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!--/.nav-collapse -->
  </div>
  <!--/.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

The final result should look something like:

[NavBar Desired Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aZtjd.jpg)

Sincere gratitude in advance.

Comment: Bootstrap's documentation for the Navbar component all include an example of integrating a form into the it: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/

Comment: Thank you! I didn't consider referring to the documentation on this occasion (which should have been an obvious point of call). I will do moving forward.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a working snippet based on **Bootstrap 3** (click to "Expand snippet"):

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      
      
      <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
        <!--div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button-->
        
        <div class="input-group">
            <div class="input-group-btn search-panel">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                    <span id="search_concept">Filter by</span> <span class="caret"></span>
                </button>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                  <li><a href="#contains">Contains</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#its_equal">It's equal</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#greather_than">Greather than ></a></li>
                  <li><a href="#less_than">Less than < </a></li>
                  <li class="divider"></li>
                  <li><a href="#all">Anything</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <input type="hidden" name="search_param" value="all" id="search_param">         
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="x" placeholder="Search term...">
            <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button class="btn btn-default" type="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></button>
            </span>
        </div>
        
      </form>
      
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">This Link here <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
</nav>
```

And also the relative CodePen: https://codepen.io/beaver71/pen/pdmBMr